# SSL for subdomain is allowing parent domain to redirect to subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl, subdomain, virtualhost

I've enabled SSL for my sub domain and everything is working great.  The problem I have is when you include https for the parent domain (which should not allow SSL connections) it redirects to the subdomain as the parent.

I'm assuming I have something in my virtualhosts entry that's incorrect.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Neither of those domains are `sub domains`, both are top level domains.

Comment: The https prefix means, that browser requires ssl handshake before taking any http content, including redirect as http header. The self signed sertificate for that domain is not valid for legal browsers.

Comment: can we see your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Without the virtual host definitions every answer would be pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing many details, but here's start.

When you specify `HTTPS://<hostname>`, the TCP message is sent to `<ip address>:443`. Not `<hostname>:443`. Your browser does the hostname->IP address conversion prior to sending anything. Your browser ALSO sticks a header `Host: <hostname>` in with the (encrypted) message.

Only on unpacking the encrypted message does the webserver get the Host header and can then (possibly) route it to a different virtual host.

But at the time of decryption, it's "already" talking with a SSL virtual host (otherwise, apache can't decrypt the message). So at that point, it attempts to figure out what the "desired" host name was (via Hosts header) and then sees if you have a :443 virtual host with that name. If not, it hands it to the default :443 virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming**:

- you are hosting the two domains on the same httpd instance
- you have only one virtualhost definition for port 443

Im also assuming that when you say "redirects to the subdomain as the parent" that you mean that the content that should only appear at the HTTPS subdomain (ie https://sub.example.com) is appearing at the HTTPS parent domain (ie https://example.com looks exactly like https://sub.example.com) and that no real HTTP redirect is occuring

**Then**:

If you have two virtualhost entries like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # using parent content
  DocumentRoot "/web/parent"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  #using subdomain content
  DocumentRoot "/web/subdomain"

  # All sorts of SSL config
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

This has the consequence that no matter what hostname you use:

- Any request to port 80 will always produce the parent content
- Any request to port 443 will always produce the subdomain content

**So:**

Try adding "NameVirtualHost *:443" (if you dont already have it) and at least a third VirtualHost:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # the default virtualhost for port 80
  # using parent content
  DocumentRoot "/web/parent"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  # the default virtualhost for port 443
  # using subdomain content
  ServerName sub.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/web/subdomain"

  # All sorts of SSL config
  ....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  # another virtualhost for port 443 
  # only activated for example.com like https://example.com/something
  # using parent content
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot "/web/parent"

  # All sorts of SSL config
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

The order of evaluation is important, so the first virtualhost becomes the default for any request that doesnt match any other virtualhost.

The third virtualhost will need to be configured for whatever you expect to happen when someone request HTTPS on the parent domain: ie do you want to redirect back to the HTTP version, or just present different content?

The [httpd command](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/httpd.html) has a -S flag that will output the current ordered virtualhost config, then exit, which is useful for diagnosing what virutal hosts are defined on what ports and the names associated

```
-S
  Show the settings as parsed from the config file (currently only shows the virtualhost settings).
```

Some config, version and platform would have been helpful on this question.

Answer (score 0):

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
#   the ssl-cert package. See
#   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
#   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
#   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```